# Enumerate environment without vertical space in tabular

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, enumerate

I am trying to typeset a hierarchical proof structure as defined by Leslie Lamport in [How to Write a Proof](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/pubs/lamport-how-to-write.pdf).

[image]

In particular, I am trying to typeset the portion

```
Assume:  1. $r \in \mathbf{Q}$
         2. $r^2 = 2$
Prove:   False
```

by putting an `enumerate` in a `tabular`.

My current best attempt is

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{10cm}}
\scshape Assume: &
\begin{enumerate}
\item $r \in \mathbf{Q}$
\item $r^2 = 2$
\end{enumerate}
\\
\scshape Prove: &
False
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, there is some rather ugly extra vertical space before and after the `enumerate` environment.
How do I get rid of this extra vertical space?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In case if you want to keep table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{lp{10cm}}
\scshape Assume: &
\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}
\begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,itemsep=-4pt]
\item $r \in \mathbf{Q}$
\item $r^2 = 2$
\end{enumerate}
\end{minipage}
\\[3ex]
\scshape Prove: &
False\\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the extra vertical space between "1." and "2."?

Comment: @ILiketoCode Certainly, use `itemsep`. I updated the answer.

Comment: How did you know the "right" value is -4pt?

Comment: @ILiketoCode I just experimented ;). Adjust to your liking please.

Answer (score 4):

I would consider doing this a little differently, and use an `itemize` environment instead:

```
\begin{itemize}
    \item[Assume]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $r \in \mathbf{Q}$
        \item $r^2 = 2$
    \end{enumerate}
    \item[Prove] False
\end{itemize}
```

[image: screenshot]

You can get the `scshape` by loading the [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package:

```
\begin{itemize}[font=\sc]
    \item[Assume]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $r \in \mathbf{Q}$
        \item $r^2 = 2$
    \end{enumerate}
    \item[Prove] False
\end{itemize}
```

[image: screenshot]

Using an `itemize` environment is beneficial because it will allow page breaks; a `tabular` environment wraps things firmly in a box.

Here's a complete MWE.

```
% arara: pdflatex
% !arara: indent: {overwrite: yes}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item[Assume]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $r \in \mathbf{Q}$
        \item $r^2 = 2$
    \end{enumerate}
    \item[Prove] False
\end{itemize}

\begin{itemize}[font=\sc]
    \item[Assume]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item $r \in \mathbf{Q}$
        \item $r^2 = 2$
    \end{enumerate}
    \item[Prove] False
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the "Prove" and "Assume" should be left aligned.

Comment: Indeed, I want "Assume" and "Prove" to be left-aligned as in Lamport's document.

Comment: @ILiketoCode You can just add `align=left` to the options passed to the list environment.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another version with `enumitem`:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\noindent some text before
\begin{description}[font=\normalfont\scshape,nosep,labelwidth=45pt,leftmargin=\dimexpr\labelwidth+\labelsep]
    \item[Assume:]
    \begin{enumerate}[leftmargin=*,nosep]
        \item $r \in \mathbf{Q}$
        \item $r^2 = 2$
    \end{enumerate}
    \item[Prove:] False
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a variation on cmhughes's solution. It uses `description` and `enumerate` with `enumitem` to define two new lists and some new commands to keep things consistent.

Anyway, the idea was to provide the following new commands:

```
\mythm
\myproofsketch
\myassume
\myprove
```

for starting the various parts of the proof. And the following environments:

```
mytheorem
```

to contain the whole thing and to list the assumptions with enumeration, respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlength{\mylstindent}
\settowidth\mylstindent{\bfseries Theorem}
\newlist{mytheoremlst}{description}{1}
\setlist[mytheoremlst]{leftmargin=0pt,itemindent=\mylstindent,style=sameline,font={\normalfont\textsc},noitemsep}
\newlist{myassumptions}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[myassumptions]{nosep,label=\arabic*.,align=left,itemindent=\mylstindent,before={\hspace*{-\mylstindent}\vspace*{-1.2em}}}
\newcommand*{\myproofsketch}{%
  \vskip 5pt
  \item[Proof Sketch:]}
\newcommand*{\myassume}{\item[Assume:]\begin{myassumptions}}
\newcommand*{\myprove}{\end{myassumptions}\item[Prove:]}
\newcommand*{\mythm}{\item[\normalfont\bfseries Theorem]}
\newenvironment{mytheorem}{%
    \begin{mytheoremlst}%
    }%
    {\end{mytheoremlst}%
    }

\begin{document}

\begin{mytheorem}
    \mythm There does not exist $r$ in $\mathbf{Q}$ such that $r^2=2$.
    \myproofsketch We assume $r^2=2$ for $r \in \mathbf{Q}$ and argue to a \emph{reductio}. Writing $r=\frac{a}{b}$ where the HCD of $a$ and $b$ is $1$, we deduce from $\frac{m}{n}^2=2$\dots
    \myassume%
        \item $r \in \mathbf{Q}$
        \item $r^2 = 2$
     \myprove False
\end{mytheorem}

\end{document}
```

Produces:

[image: Theorem layout with new commands]

Can anybody suggest a better way of setting up `myassumption` to get the first assumption aligned vertically with 'Assume:' without losing the horizontal alignment with the second assumption? This is somewhat of a hack and likely fragile...

Comment: +1 This is interesting, as it moves one step further towards automating the hierarchical proof structure by Lamport by defining new environments and commands.