# Enumeration inside tables - how to eliminate vertical space before and after?

Tags: tables, enumerate, enumitem

I want to produce a table which contains enumerations inside certain cells. However, before and after the enumeration there is a vertical space that looks not good. Is it possible to eliminate this space so that the enumeration starts and ends on the same line as the text in the cells left and right of the enumeration? And how to do so?

And a related question: How to avoid the numbers to be indented?

Currently, I'm using the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{import}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{epsfig}
%\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper, margin=1.2in}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}{../images/}}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small,skip=10pt}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}

\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}[]
\small
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ p{4cm} p{5cm} p{6cm} p{6cm} }
\hline\hline    
         Construct & Nominal Definition & Empirical Indicators & Operationalization  \\
\hline         
         Associational Solidarity & Frequency and patterns of interaction in various types of activities in which family members engage & \begin{enumerate}[nosep] \item Frequency of intergenerational interaction (i.e., face-to-face, telephone, mail) \item Types of common activities shared (i.e., recreation, special occasions, etc.) \end{enumerate} & About how many friends, other than members of your family, do you have who are younger than 30?

         Which option best describes whether or not you can discuss personal issues such as feelings, beliefs or experiences with any of these friends?\\
\hline
         Affectual Solidarity & Type and degree of positive sentiments held about family members, and the degree of reciprocity of these sentiments & \begin{enumerate}[nosep] \item Ratings of affection, warmth, close-ness, understanding, trust, respect, etc. for family members \item Ratings of perceived reciprocity in positive sentiments among family members \end{enumerate} & Tell me overall how negative or posi-tive you feel towards people in their 20s? \\
\hline         
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]

Thanks for help!

Comment: [This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/162810/134144) seems to be quite similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried like this:

```
\begin{table}[]
\small
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{ p{4cm} p{5cm} p{6cm} p{6cm} }
\hline\hline    
         Construct & Nominal Definition & Empirical Indicators & Operationalization  \\
\hline         
         Associational Solidarity & Frequency and patterns of interaction in various types of activities in which family members engage &\begin{enumerate}[nosep,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip/2\relax}] \item Frequency of intergenerational interaction (i.e., face-to-face, telephone, mail) \item Types of common activities shared (i.e., recreation, special occasions, etc.) \end{enumerate} & About how many friends, other than members of your family, do you have who are younger than 30?

         Which option best describes whether or not you can discuss personal issues such as feelings, beliefs or experiences with any of these friends?\\
\hline
         Affectual Solidarity & Type and degree of positive sentiments held about family members, and the degree of reciprocity of these sentiments &\begin{enumerate}[nosep,after=\vspace{-\baselineskip},before=\vspace{-\dimexpr\baselineskip/2\relax}] \item Ratings of affection, warmth, close-ness, understanding, trust, respect, etc. for family members \item Ratings of perceived reciprocity in positive sentiments among family members \end{enumerate} & Tell me overall how negative or posi-tive you feel towards people in their 20s? \\
\hline         
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{tab:my_label}
\end{table}
```

and gives:

[image]

I don't really know if \baselineskip/2 is used for the begining of an enumeration... It may be works "by accident"... but it works here.